# Upgrade issue from jetty 9.4.8 to jetty 9.4.14

Tags: jetty

Upgraded client application to the higher version where higher version java application is using 9.4.14 version of jetty.

The issue here is we are trying to reuse keystore SSL generated with root CA from 9.4.8 and keystore is failing to support jetty 9.4.14 version.

No errors in logs, but while trying to access in URL

[image]

Do we have to make any changes in the root certificate also when we do jetty upgrade?

Used Java version: 8

Comment: Please share more details - is there any error you are facing? If yes, what have you tried to resolve it?

Comment: Except below warning,

Comment: Weak cipher suite  for few cipher , except this, no ssl handshake error in logs

Comment: Please edit your question to contain all information, along with your debugging attempts

Comment: Your logs should indicate what is going on.  How are you using Jetty?  How did you upgrade?  We need more details please.  There's not enough information provided to help you.